# Best practice to get a list of data from Firebase and share it in different activities/fragments

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm, dagger

I am learning to properly use MVVM, Dagger2 and Firebase on Android using java. I was wondering what would be the best way to do the following:

1. I need to download a list of data from Firebase once
2. Use the data in a couple of fragments in one activity.

In order to not repeat the procedure of downloading the data from Firebase when creating every new fragment (or activity). Thank you.

Comment: I think this **[article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-inject-a-viewmodel-directly-into-an-activity-when-getting-data-from-firestore-633cf8efe60a)** might help.

Answer (score 1):

load the data into your main activity and pass it to whatever fragment or activity needs it. Heres how to pass data from activity to fragment: [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Heres how to pass data activity to activity:
[How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)